# Characterizing uncountable connected topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, connectedness

We know that if $X$ is a connected metric space with more than one point , then $X$ is uncountable ; can we characterize those connected topological spaces for which more than one point implies uncountability ?

Comment: could you recall what being connected mean, please?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Are you asking for topological properties $\Phi$ such that every connected $\Phi$-space of size at least two is uncountable? Would $\Phi = \text{uncountable}$ be acceptable?

Comment: @zap: a connected space is one which can't be divided into two disjoint nonempty open sets.

Answer (score 2):

As this question is posed, it does not make much sense.

We can list some classes of topological spaces for which the property
$$\mbox{if $X$ has at least two points, then X is uncountable}$$
holds. Let's make some examples.

1. The class of connected metric spaces (as you stated)
2. The class of spaces with one point (in this case the property is vacuously satisfied)
3. The class of non-discrete complete metric spaces
4. The class of connected Hausdorff compact spaces
5. The class of uncountable spaces
6. Any subclass of the preceding classes

As you can see, a lot of classes of spaces satisfy this property, but I hardly see how one can characterize them all.

Comment: I think one can add the class of connected Baire spaces in which every point is closed. This includes the connected locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It is even true that every functionally Hausdorff connected space with at least two points has size at least continuum. In turn, every $T_3$ connected space with at least two points is uncountable (a countable one would be $T_4$ and hence functionally Hausdorff). On the other hand there exists a countably infinite connected Hausdorff (even Urysohn) space.